# How to set group name when consuming messages in kafka using command line?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Any idea how to set group name when consuming messages in kafka using command line.

I tried with the following command :

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic nil_RF2_P2 --from-beginning --config group.id=test1
'config' is not a recognized option
```

The goal is to find the offset of consumed messages with the following command:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --zookeeper localhost:2181 --group test1
```

Can somebody help in this regards!!

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic nil_RF2_P2 --from-beginning **--consumer-property group.id=test1**

In case you specify the flag **--from-beginning** just remember that the consumer group should not have consumed any records in the past or else your consumer will start consuming from the earliest not consumed record by the specified group (and not from the actual beginning, as you may 
incorrectly assume).

Comment: It works only if one replaces `--zookeeper localhost:2181` with `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092`.

Answer (score 20):

Got the answer to change the groupname from command prompt!!

steps:

1. create a new `consumer.properties` file, say `consumer1.properties`.
2. change `group.id=<Give a new group name>` in the `consumer1.properties`.
3. `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topicname --from-beginning --consumer.config config/consumer1.properties --delete-consumer-offsets`

Comment: Is there a list of all possible options (and their formats) accepted in this properties file?

Comment: @chunk_split they are available here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Comment: Or you can directly use `--consumer-property group.id=XXXX` instead of creating a conflig file (or `--group` since the 1.x).

Comment: @Nilotpal are you trying to delete messages from the given topic here ?? with --delete-consumer-offsets

Answer (score 4):

if you want change group id without lost offset of record you have get offset manually of current Group.id and set to new run consumer that have new id. if don't have any control to get offset in consumer instance you can run this command.

```
/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --new-consumer --bootstrap-server <ip_address>:<Broker_port>  --group Group_name --describe
```

and then you can seek data from specific offset. pay attention you should call seek after call poll، Assign command not work. 
also you can see my sample of code in github

[Example here](https://github.com/jeus/kafka-example)

Comment: i guess kafka-consumer-groups.sh utility is only present from 0.10.0.0 onwards and not in 0.8.2.x versions of kafka!!

Comment: @Nilotpal ooh yes i forget this. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the --group option like this (tested with Kafka 2.0.0):

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group test-consumer --topic test --from-beginning`

Comment: Work since the 1.x version I think. Not with the 0.10.x version (you can use `--consumer-property group.id=XXXX` instead).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash then you can use its process substitution capability.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
--topic nil_RF2_P2 --from-beginning \
--consumer.config <(echo group.id=test1)
```