# In Kafka, cannot create new consumer using kafka-consumer-groups.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, hdf

I set up a Kafka standalone node(HDF ver 3.1.1, Kafka ver 1.0.0)

To load data from kafka, one can create consumer group using kafka-consumer-groups.sh

The command is like the following:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:6667 (--new-consumer) --describe --group logstash
```

But it results in the following error:

```
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to The consumer group command timed out while waiting for group to initialize:
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: kafka-consumer-groups.sh does not create a consumer group...You create clients with group.id for that...

Comment: @JustinPihony thank you. I solve the problem using this link :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549867/how-to-set-group-name-when-consuming-messages-in-kafka-using-command-line/38553588?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

The following will create a consumer under `group-1` (and create the group if it doesn't exist already):

`kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic topic --from-beginning--consumer-property group.id=group-1`

Also refer the following question:
[how to set group name when consuming messages in kafka using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549867/how-to-set-group-name-when-consuming-messages-in-kafka-using-command-line)